# Error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm new to django and am trying to get the sum of all `Gross_amount`, `Withholding_tax`, `Net_amount` for each month a year and I keep getting this error :

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function sum(character varying) does not exist
>   LINE 1: ..."."Date_recieved" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS "month", SUM("pv_pv...
>                                                                ^
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

This is my code:

```
class Dashboard(ListView):
   template_name = 'pv/dashboard.html'
   table =Pv.objects.annotate(month = TruncMonth('Date_recieved'))

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      today = datetime.now()
      context = super(Dashboard, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['table_pv'] = self.table.values('month').annotate(G=Sum('Gross_amount'), 
      T=Sum('Withholding_tax'),
 N=sum('Net_amount')).values('month','G','T').filter(Date_recieved__year=today.year).order_by()
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Sum` (with capital S)? `from django.db.models import Sum`

Comment: It seems like you are using Python's built-in [**`sum()`**--PyDocs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?#sum), It should be Django's [**`Sum()`**--DjangoDoc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum)

Comment: @PedramParsian i imported the Sum and Changed it to Sum but got this error unction sum(character varying) does not exist LINE 1: ..."."Date_recieved" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS "month", SUM("pv_pv... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.                                          ^

Comment: @TERKPEHMENSAH Would you please _edit_ your question and add the full traceback there?

Comment: is working now , i changed the gross amount, withholding tax and net amount to positive integer field instead of charfield